# How to change option after hitting Cmd+Q with just the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, big-sur

I am trying to exit Skitch using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. When I hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, I get a pop-up that says:

```
Discard Current Skitch Note
You are about to discard the current Skitch Note. You cannot undo this action.
```

I have two options to choose from:

```
Discard Skitch Note
Cancel
```

However **Cancel** is the only one that is highlighted. How can I change the option to **Discard Skitch Note**, using only the keyboard?

EDIT: I am using an M1 MacBook Air... if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried using the **Tab** or **Arrow** keys?

Comment: Tab or the Arrow keys do not seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this dialog uses standard macOS UI components, you can enable keyboard navigation for these controls (previously called Full Keyboard Access) in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → ‘Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls’.

With this option enabled, Tab changes focus and Space activates the focused control. Enter continues to activate the default button.